# Using getters as model properties

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

Using playframework, it it possible to use a getter as a model column definition? I tried this:

```
    @Column(name="filename")
    public String getFilename() {
        return getFile().getName();
    }
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible.
You could define the model column as usual and then if you need, you can define an specific function to get some especial feature.

Hope this helps.

Marta

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://www.avaje.org/doc/ebean-userguide.pdf) (sadly PDF so it is not easily linked):

> ```
> @Column
> Use this if the naming convention does not match the bean property name to the database
> column or if you need to use quoted identifiers. Otherwise it is not required.
> ```

All the examples throughout refer to "property" (which I take to mean field).  There are no examples which show annotating a method.